# Python multiprocessing freezes code in Ubuntu

Tags: python, multithreading, ubuntu, multiprocessing, starmap

I am trying to run a piece of python code that calls the starmap function

```
result = self.pool.starmap(CURR_CODE.__some_func__, args)
```

I ran this on arch linux and had no issues.
However, when I ran this on ubuntu, the code freezes. I don't get any output, nothing gets printed on the screen.

All my libraries are in a conda package in the ubuntu. This is not the case when I run the code on arch linux.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` on Arch, copy that file to a fresh virtualenv in Ubuntu, and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` there to make sure you're using exactly the same package version numbers.

Comment: I the computer in which the code works just uses the system libraries. No pip or conda. The computer in which it doesnt work uses conda and conda gave me a list of libraries that it has in the environment. How can i compare this with the system libraries. Is there a way to list the system libraries?

Comment: I'm assuming by "system libraries" you mean the Python packages found in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, for example? You can list the system libraries using `pip`. If it's not installed yet, just run `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade --user`. (I strongly advise against installing packages globally unless *absolutely* necessary.)